# É possível expulsar um usuário que esteja logado?

Tags: php

Supondo que o usuário esteja logado por meio da `$_SESSION` no `PHP` e eu queira apagar seu perfil (por meio de uma conta administrativa) do banco de dados, em seguida ele deveria perder sua sessão na próxima atualização ou requisição de pagina, como poderia proceder sem a necessidade de comparar com o banco de dados de tempo em tempo? Seria necessário o uso de um websocket nesse caso? Seria necessário habilitar alguma extensão no php.ini?

Comment: Você tem persistido o id da sessão do usuário em questão?

Comment: Você pode fazer algum middleware ou até mesmo alguma verificação em uma função que é sempre utilizada no sistema para verificar se o usuário ainda tem permisão de permanecer no sistema, caso não tenha solicita o logout.

Comment: Primeiro antes de mais nada, ao carregar a página, implemente um código que verifica se o usuário dele existe no banco de dados, e se existe, verifica se os dados da sessão do usuário correspondem aos dados do banco de dados, acrescenta-se aí uma segurança a mais, depois se, o usuário não estiver incluso na base de dados, ou se os dados não corresponderem entre a sessão do usuário e a do banco de dados, você encerra a sessão dele e redireciona, exemplo: unset($_SESSION['nomeDaSessao']); header('Location: index.php');

Comment: Inclua o código em algum arquivo onde é carregado em todas as páginas, um include() ou require() existente, se não existir, faça um arquivo separado e antes faça a conexão com o banco de dados, depois a verificação toda, e inclua nas suas páginas PHP.